# How to refill a variable after loading page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This function, ajax ... every thing is working well.
When I want to reload the $users it return the same $users
Is there any way after loading ajax to reload the $users with new data?

Controller

```
function list_of_users_by_skills($project_ids){

         $project_id = json_decode($project_ids);
            /* Generate Users by Skills 
            * By Isaac
            */ 
           $this->loadModel('Training');                              

           //Get list of users by skills
           $users_return = $this->Training->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Training.Project_id' => $project_id)));

            //some code here to return the $users :)

           asort($users); 
           $this->set('users', $users);                            
    }
```

View

```
var page = 'http://localhost/index.php/shifts/list_of_users_by_skills/[176,196]/'; 
               console.log(page);

                $.ajax({                          
                      url: page,                          
                      success: function(data) {
                          <?php  echo "var user_array = [" . json_encode($users) . "];\n"; ?>
                            console.log(user_array);    
                           console.log(<?php echo json_encode($users); ?>);
                      }                      
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hard-coded your users variable in your javascript:

```
<?php  echo "var user_array = [" . json_encode($users) . "];\n"; ?>
```

This will only be filled once, on the initial page request.

You need to make sure that the script that you are calling with ajax, returns the actual user list and use that:

Something like:

```
$.ajax({                          
       url: page,
       dataType: "json",                    
       success: function(data) {
            var user_array = data;
            console.log(user_array);
       }                      
});
```

And your `page` script should do something like this at the end:

```
 echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: Yeyyyy!!!!!!Thank you Some much. I printed some HTML tag before to retrive it for an other thing. It is working like a charm. ;)

Comment: @Vahid Rajaei Good to hear :-)

Answer (score 1):

you're pushing the same user_array on the succes callback...

You should declare the var before the function and overwrite the var ín the function{

```
var page = 'http://localhost/index.php/shifts/list_of_users_by_skills/[176,196]/';
var users =  [<?php echo json_encode($users);  // or make in an array so json_encode is sufficient ?>];
$.ajax({                          
    url: page,                          
    success: function(data) {
        users = data.users;
    }                      
});
```

where you're gateway (the PHP side of things) would return an array (or object) with a key 'users' => array(user1, user2 etc etc);